# csv file containing 2 rows and 2 columns is not rendered in R markdown

Tags: r, csv, r-markdown

I'm trying to display a CSV file in R markdown, but it's not showing up. I use the same code for other CSV files, and it works fine. There are no errors, just an empty space.

The only difference between this CSV file and the others is that this one is exceptionally small (2 columns, 2 rows, each of the 4 cells containing a single word.)

The code that i used is this:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Me"
date: "1/8/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r echo = FALSE, results = 'asis', include = FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
```  

```{r echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
data <- select(read.csv("test.csv", stringsAsFactors = F))
kable(data, caption = "This is data.") %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "bordered", full_width = T) %>% scroll_box(width = "100%", height = "200px")
```
````

[test.csv download](https://github.com/errslima/data/blob/master/test.csv)

edit: here is the absolute shortest code i could make, replicating the error. this only contains essential code that is used to read and display the csv file.

````
```{r}
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

data <- select(read.csv("test.csv"))
kable(data)
```
````

Comment: nothing changes.

Comment: Have you tried removing `select()`? I am not sure why you would need it there, but I tried to open a dummy file and `select(read.csv)` returns `data frame with 0 columns and 5 rows`. remove `select()` and everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the use of `select`:

```
data <- select(read.csv("test1.csv", stringsAsFactors = F))
data
```

```
> data
data frame with 0 columns and 1 row
```

If your remove `select`:

```
data <- read.csv("test1.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
data

> data
  column1 coumn2
1  value1 value2
```